# Regular expression to find one of two strings when one consists the other

Tags: regex, string, postgresql

It's to be used in PostgreSQL.
I have set of strings, for example:

```
xxx Heartbeat
yyy Heartbeat
xxx Code Red Entry/Exit
yyy Code Red Entry/Exit
xxx TFTP Server Heartbeat
yyy TFTP Server Heartbeat
```

I need to split that second part which is after unknown strings xxx/yyy that can have spaces inside. Before I had search strings that do not cross and was using sort of:

```
SUBSTRING(description, '(?i).*(Code Red Entry/Exit|TFTP Server Heartbeat).?')
```

But after I've got another (Heartbeat) option, this regex started to only select "Heartbeat" in all cases if I use

```
SUBSTRING(description, '(?i).*(Code Red Entry/Exit|TFTP Server Heartbeat|Heartbeat).?')
```

How can I fix it?

Upd.
Basicaly I need a regexp substitute to a next code:

```
CASE WHEN description ILIKE '%TFTP Server Heartbeat' THEN 'TFTP Server Heartbeat' 
     WHEN description ILIKE '%Heartbeat' THEN 'Heartbeat' 
     WHEN description ILIKE '%Code Red Entry/Exit' THEN 'Code Red Entry/Exit' 
 etc... 
END
```

Comment: What is the logic here for searching?  Do you want to find certain keywords within these strings?  Or, are you just trying to match the entire strings themselves?

Comment: I'm trying to find exact strings themselves. And if I have "TFTP Server Heartbeat" - I need to have output "TFTP Server Heartbeat" not the "Heartbeat". Otherwise if I have some text ending with "Heartbeat" without "TFTP Server" - I need to get "Heartbeat". And in reality I have like 15 different options currently, but cross-matching only "TFTP Server Heartbeat" and "Heartbeat"

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions as follow:

```
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_MATCHES(description, '^\y(TFTP Server Heartbeat|Heartbeat|Code Red Entry/Exit)\y$', 'g'), '')
FROM yourTable
WHERE description ~ '\y(TFTP Server Heartbeat|Heartbeat|Code Red Entry/Exit)\y'
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks, but xxx or yyy are not just words - they are some unknown strings. I want to find exact matches to the last words and in case of "Heartbeat"/"TFTP Server Heartbeat" I want to match them with the logic if I have "TFTP Server Heartbeat" - I need to have output "TFTP Server Heartbeat" not the "Heartbeat"; otherwise if I have some text ending with "Heartbeat" without "TFTP Server" - I need to get "Heartbeat".

Comment: @DenysSmakovskyi Um...my answer makes no assumption about what `xxx` and `yyy` actually are, other than that they are single non whitespace words which come before the text you want to match.  You should make your question more clear if this answer doesn't meet your expectations.

Comment: I need a regexp substitute to a next code:
CASE WHEN description ilike '%TFTP Server Heartbeat' then 'TFTP Server Heartbeat'
WHEN description ilike '%Heartbeat' then 'Heartbeat'
WHEN description ilike '%Code Red Entry/Exit' then 'Code Red Entry/Exit'
etc...
END

Comment: Will the matching terms always appear as the last thing in the column, or could they be buried anywhere in the string?

Comment: Yes, they are last thing in the column

Comment: No, this doesn't work as expected. This works only if the first part "xxx" or "yyy" is a single word without spaces. Once it has spaces - it captures all that is after the first space and ends with these strings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm totally missing the boat, but it sounds like you just want the matching string if it's one of those three strings.

If that's the case and you are using regex, would a simple substring not work?

```
select
  substring (description from 'TFTP Server Heartbeat|Code Red Entry/Exit|Heartbeat')
```

Results on sample data:

```
Heartbeat
Heartbeat
Code Red Entry/Exit
Code Red Entry/Exit
TFTP Server Heartbeat
TFTP Server Heartbeat
```